# XenServer 6.5.0 tapdisk experienced an error

Tags: xenserver

I have just deployed XenServer 6.5.0 on a physical box. I connect to it with XenCenter client. I am able to create a VM, but when i start it, I get the following error: `tapdisk experienced an error`. The server has SAS harddrives (RAID 0) and the CPU knows virtualization.

The logs show this:

```
2015-02-11 08:50:09,918 WARN  XenAdmin.Network.TaskPoller [21] - Action failed due to API failure:
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at XenAdmin.Network.TaskPoller.poll()
   at XenAdmin.Network.TaskPoller.PollToCompletion()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.VMActions.VMStartAction.DoAction(Int32 start, Int32 end)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.VMActions.VMStartAbstractAction.StartOrResumeVmWithHa(Int32 start, Int32 end)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.VMActions.VMStartAction.Run()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction.RunWorkerThread(Object o)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
2015-02-11 08:50:09,937 INFO  XenAPI.Session [21] - Invoking XML-RPC method task.destroy
2015-02-11 08:50:09,986 ERROR XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction [21] - tapdisk experienced an error
2015-02-11 08:50:09,986 ERROR XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction [21] -    at XenAdmin.Network.TaskPoller.poll()
   at XenAdmin.Network.TaskPoller.PollToCompletion()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.VMActions.VMStartAction.DoAction(Int32 start, Int32 end)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.VMActions.VMStartAbstractAction.StartOrResumeVmWithHa(Int32 start, Int32 end)
   at XenAdmin.Actions.VMActions.VMStartAction.Run()
   at XenAdmin.Actions.AsyncAction.RunWorkerThread(Object o)
2015-02-11 08:50:09,987 WARN  Audit [21] - Operation failure: VMStartAction: myTestLab: VM 92403395-5fcb-e3e7-e880-a0b9eb2b1eb7 (Windows Server 2012 R2): Host d0aa6ff1-15ce-4020-b99e-5bf95ded8c3f (myTestLab): Starting
2015-02-11 08:50:09,987 DEBUG XenAdmin.Actions.ActionBase [21] - tapdisk experienced an error
```

I would appreciate any advise because I was unable to find anything related to this on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same error, so start try take some informations.

When you do the upgrade seme VM's lose the Xen Drivers for keybord and DVD driver, so can't detect it, specially if you did the upgrade with xentools.iso on it. To solve that i remove the VM, but not the disks, so i create a nev VM and atached the disks, worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is caused by ISOs mounted no longer available.

You can do a `tail -F /var/log/SMlog` to see the detailed message, if it is the same as what Andrew Paternoster mentioned.

Do the following in pool master dom0 will help to eject all mounted ISOs in VMs

`xe vm-cd-eject --multiple`

Comment: This worked for me. But I did "eject" on a vm from XenCenter.

Comment: Doing it from XenCenter is equivalent to `vm-cd-eject` for a single VM ;-D

Comment: Yes, exactly it is.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading a few of our Xenservers to 6.5 I moved a few hard drives from some troublesome servers. I found that after they were remounted I would get a error saying "tapdisk experienced an error". After a bit of digging around in the logs I found:

> Server_helpers.exec exception_handler: Got exception
>   SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_449: [ ; tapdisk experienced an error [opterr=No
>   medium found]; ]

I checked the VDI's and I could access them via a live CD I mount in the VM. After I rebooted and ejected the CD I found the VM would now boot. I tried the same thing on the 2 other servers that would boot and now they are all happy. It seems that when you create a VM for the first time it needs to boot from the CD drive at least once to fix this error.

Hopefully this saves some one some time.  I spent a few hours on this and couldn't find any real useful info on it.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced this issue while installing from a NFS repository. The ISO was readable only by owner so Xen could not read it.

Answer (score 0):

I hav updated all my drivers (firmware and RAID/PERC drivers for dell 1950) and then installed AGAIN Xenserver 6.5.

It s now working out of the box.

My DELL BIOS was 2.0.x now its 2.7.0 so it was really old.

Try it, must work.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Xenserver 6.5 host. Had to change the DVD drive on the VM in XenCenter before it would boot. I think it was referencing the physical DVD drive on the host.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, in fact, your file is probably not readable by "others" in NFS server. Allowing read at least solved completely the problem!